# Using dom to get content from table with no id

Tags: dom, html-table

I don't know how to get values from tables that don't have an ID.

I would like to use DOM to get the value "03" from

```
<tr><th scope='row'>Total WUs</th><td>03</td></tr>
```

but the table doesn't have an ID.  It is the first table on the page.  I'll give a code printout of the whole table:

```
<table cellspacing='0' rules='all' border='1' style='border-collapse:collapse;'><tr><th scope='row'>User Name</th><td>laughing_squid</td></tr><tr><th scope='row'>Project Rank</th><td>1,156,036</td></tr><tr><th scope='row'>Team Rank</th><td>2</td></tr><tr><th scope='row'>Total Points</th><td>207</td></tr><tr><th scope='row'>Total WUs</th><td>03</td></tr><tr><th scope='row'>Points Yesterday</th><td>NA</td></tr><tr><th scope='row'>Points Today</th><td>69</td></tr><tr><th scope='row'>PPD Average</th><td>138</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out, this script uses JQuery which can be downloaded from [here](http://www.jquery.com):

```
$('table td').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

if you need only the value `03` then use following:

```
console.log($('table td:eq(4)').text());
```

Comment: Can I do this in a php script, instead of the console window, and it will give me a value? Do you have any good links to learn about it?